# Proposition 2.6.3 Introduction to Real Analysis by Jiri Lebl

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> [image]

This proof comes from Introduction to Real Analysis by Jiri Lebl. I do not understand one step in the proof, which is marked by the arrow on the photo. Can you explain how that inequality holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is a slight error in the proof you quoted above. Instead of $Q := \max \sigma(\{1, \dots, K\})$, let $Q := \max \sigma(\{1, \dots, N\})$. Then in the step you indicate, the sum of rearranged terms $$\sum_{n=1, \sigma(n) > M}^N |x_{\sigma(n)}|$$ is replaced by the sum of original terms $$\sum_{n=M+1}^Q |x_n|.$$ Why is the second sum larger than the first? The first sum adds up terms $|x_{\sigma(n)}|$ such that $\sigma(n) > M$ **and** $\sigma(n) < Q$ by our new choice of $Q$. This includes some, but not necessarily all, of the terms $|x_{M+1}|, |x_{M+2}|, \dots, |x_Q|$. The second sum, on the other hand, contains all of those (nonnegative) terms, hence the inequality.

This new choice of $Q$ doesn't change anything else in the argument.

Answer (score 1):

The introduction of $Q$ isn't even necessary, because in the beginning $M$ is chosen such that

- $\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty}|x_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Hence, by definition of $K$ you have immediately (because all summands have an index larger than $M$)

$$\sum_{n=1,\sigma(n)>M}^N|x_{\sigma(n)}| \leq \sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty}|x_n| <  \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $m=\sigma(n)$. For each $n$ in the first sum, $m>M$ and $m\le Q$. So
the $\sigma(n)$ with $1\le \sigma\le N$ and $\sigma(n)>M$ all lie in the
set $\{M+1,\ldots,Q\}$. As $\sigma$ is injective, the $|x_{\sigma(n)}|$
in the first sum form a subset of the terms in the second, which must then
be at least the same size as the first.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1, \sigma(n)>M}^N |x_{\sigma(n)}| = \sum_{n=1, \sigma(n) \geq M+1}^N |x_{\sigma(n)}|$$

We reindex by $\sigma(n) $. We see that $\sigma(n) \geq M+1$ and by definition, at most $\sigma(n) \leq Q$. Moreover, we take all terms and not just those for which our permutation $\sigma$ maps our indices of $x$ to. That is,

$$\sum_{n=1, \sigma(n)>M}^N |x_{\sigma(n)}| = \sum_{n=1, \sigma(n) \geq M+1}^N |x_{\sigma(n)}| \leq \sum_{ \sigma(n) \geq M+1}^Q |x_{\sigma(n)}| $$

Lastly, we simply let $n := \sigma(n)$.

$$\sum_{n=1, \sigma(n)>M}^N |x_{\sigma(n)}| = \sum_{n=1, \sigma(n) \geq M+1}^N |x_{\sigma(n)}| \leq \sum_{ \sigma(n) \geq M+1}^Q |x_{\sigma(n)}| = \sum_{ n = M+1}^Q |x_{n}|$$